# MVC JsonResult Controller parameter null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**HTML**

```
 <a href="@item.documentId" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle del-file"></a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".del-file").click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        var jsonData = "{'doc':'" + $(this).attr('href') + "'}";

        var parent_row = $(this).closest('tr');

        $.post('@Url.Action("Delete","Documents")', jsonData)
            .success(function (response) {
                if (response.result == true) {
                    $(parent_row).remove();
                }
            })
            .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                } else {
                    alert('Unexpected error.');
                }
            })
        return false;
    })
```

**MVC Controller Method**

```
public JsonResult Delete(string doc)
    {            
        long docId = Helpers.Utility.Instance.getIdAfterDecode(doc);            
        if (docId <=0)
        {
            return Json(new { result = "error: Document info was not correct." });
        }
        bool output = new DocumentsInfoRepository().deleteDocument(docId);
        return Json(new { result = output});
    }
```

doc is always null, what am I missing. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Just `var jsonData = { doc: $(this).attr('href') };` (no quotes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke .  great quick solution. Thanksss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your json constrruction you have to construct like this.

```
 var jsonData = {doc:$(this).attr('href')};
```

as you are sending a post request to an action it's better to add `[HttpPost]` attribute on actions.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Delete(string doc)
```